# Multiple properties in same ECS component

Tags: java, design-patterns, libgdx

I understand the ECS pattern and what it aims to solve. However I'm struggling to find the best way to identify the components.

For example, I'm working on a game where you have a ship and you can attack other players/npc and collect resources.

Do I need to have a component for each property or can I group *apparently unrelated* properties in the same component?

E.g, with a component per property it would look like this:

```
// Components
Position {
    int x, y;
}
Velocity {
    int speed;
    double direction;
}
Sprite {
    Image[] images;
}
Health {
    int health;
}
Name {
    String name;
}
Resource {
    // Tag for resources.
}

// Entities
MapEntity {
    Position position;
    Sprite sprite;
}
ResourceEntity {
    Position position;
    Sprite sprite;
    Resource resource;
}
ShipEntity {
    Position position;
    Sprite sprite;
    Velocity velocity;
    Health health;
    Name name;
}
```

With multiple components per property it would look like this:

```
// Components
MapObject {
    int x, y; // Position
    Image[] images; // Sprite
}
Resource {
    // Tag for resources
}
Velocity { // separated component for static map entities
    int speed;
    double direction;
}
Ship {
    int health
    String name;
}

// Entities
MapEntity {
    MapObject mapObject;
}
ResourceEntity {
    MapObject mapObject;
    Resource resource;
}
Ship {
    MapObject mapObject;
    Velocity velocity;
    Ship ship;
}
```

I don't think it will make a difference, but I'm using LibGDX's Ashley framework.

Answer (score 0):

I usually group properties with the systems that use them.

For instance you would have a system for animation and a system for rendering. You would then have a texture component which contains all texture related data, and an animation component which contains all animation related data.

If you have some data that is used by multiple systems then keep them separate like a transform component which holds the entity position, rotation, size etc. Which would then be used by both the animation system and the render system.

In your example data you would keep position and velocity in the same component as they will most likely both be used for working out the position of the entity.

However, these are not set rules and you can have all components separate which will give you more flexibility later. For example you may want to add a system later which only works on entities that have a velocity. Having the components separate allows you to create a family from the component with out any changes to the current systems. If you had your velocity in a transform component you would then have to separate it to create a family or use the transform component and add some condition in your system.